# Connect eventHandler after Handlebars Template loading

Tags: javascript, html, templates, handlebars.js, jquery-events

What is the proper way to connect all the handlers (e.g. for button clicks) automagically after the Handlebars template is loaded (probably using jQuery)?

I mean is there any alternative to add the event handlers after adding the template, every time I load the template? Any alternative to

```
$('#id').html(template(data))
$('#button1').click(action1)
$('#button2').click(action2)
$('#button3').click(action3)
…
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do some event delegation:

```
$('#id').on('click', '#button1', action1);
$('#id').on('click', '#button2', action1);
$('#id').on('click', '#button3', action1);
```